# Design a data source independent application using batch data

Tags: java, mongodb, postgresql, design-patterns, spring-kafka

We have a legacy application that reads data from mongo for each user (query result is small to large based on user request)  and our app creates a file for each user and drops to FTP server /s3. We are reading data as mongo cursor and writing each batch to file as soon it gets batch data so file writing performance is decent. This application works great but bound to mongo and mongo cursor.

Now we have to redesign this application as we have to support different data sources i.e MongoDB, Postgres DB, Kinesis, S3, etc. We have thought below ideas so far:

1. Build data APIs for each source and expose a paginated REST response. This is a feasible solution but it might be slow for large
   query data compare to the current cursor response.
2. Build a data abstraction layer by feeding  batch data in kafka and read batch data stream in our file generator.but most of the time user asks for sorted data so we would need to read messages in sequence. We will lose benefit of great throughput and lot of extra work to combine these data message before writing to file.

We are looking for a solution to replace the current mongo cursor and make our file generator independent of the data source.

Comment: How does the data comes to mongodb ? It is continuously updated or static and has been populated for good. As I understand this is queried and hence desired to be put into Kafka analogous to some event data. I was wondering if it is possible to replace mongo by kafka.

Comment: Our mongo data is updated couple of times in a day in batches using ETLs.The challenge is we have to apply lot filtering and sorting so if we put sorted data in kafka , while retrieval we need to make sure received data in order .Our need is not streaming mostly its batching writing to file .We have to read data from postgres/mongo only as our data files are for incremental and history data too.kafka would have been good fit if only we needed incremental files

Comment: I would see if this batches can directly write to Kafka. If you are using mongo for anything else they can write there too if not skip mongo.Again this is just a suggestion but for me writing to mongo and then to kafka sounds little awkward to me. Moreever this data can be divided into multiple topics as per query requirements and corresponding consumer can directly read from the topic they desire

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you essentially want to create an API where you can maintain the efficiency of streaming as much as possible, as you are doing with writing the file while you are reading the user data.

In that case, you might want to define a push-parser API for your `ReadSource`s which will stream data to your `WriteTarget`s which will write the data to anything that you have an implementation for. Sorting will be handled on the `ReadSource` side of things since for some sources you can read in an ordered manner (such as from databases); For those sources for which you can't do this you might simply perform an intermediate step to sort your data (such as write to a temporary table) then stream it to the `WriteTarget`.

A basic implementation might look vaguely like this:

```
public class UserDataRecord {
    private String data1;
    private String data2;

    public String getRecordAsString() {
        return data1 + "," + data2;
    }
}
```

---

```
public interface WriteTarget<Record> {
    /** Write a record to the target */
    public void writeRecord(Record record);

    /** Finish writing to the target and save everything */
    public void commit();

    /** Undo whatever was written */
    public void rollback();
}
```

---

```
public abstract class ReadSource<Record> {
    protected final WriteTarget<Record> writeTarget;

    public ReadSource(WriteTarget<Record> writeTarget) { this.writeTarget = writeTarget; }

    public abstract void read();
}
```

---

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class RelationalDatabaseReadSource extends ReadSource<UserDataRecord> {
    private Connection dbConnection;

    public RelationalDatabaseReadSource (WriteTarget<UserDataRecord> writeTarget, Connection dbConnection) {
        super(writeTarget);
        this.dbConnection = dbConnection;
    }

    @Override public void read() {
        // read user data from DB and encapsulate it in a record
        try (Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("Select * From TABLE Order By COLUMNS");) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                UserDataRecord record = new UserDataRecord();
                // stream the records to the write target
                writeTarget.writeRecord(record);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
public class FileWriteTarget implements WriteTarget<UserDataRecord> {
    private File fileToWrite;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    public FileWriteTarget(File fileToWrite) throws IOException {
        this.fileToWrite = fileToWrite;
        this.writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileToWrite));
    }

    @Override public void writeRecord(UserDataRecord record) {
        writer.println(record.getRecordAsString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    @Override public void commit() {
        // write trailing records
        writer.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void rollback() {
        try { writer.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
        fileToWrite.delete();
    }
}
```

---

This is just the general idea and needs serious improvement. 
Anyone please feel free to update this API.